# Generating a dynamic nested map based on a Split String and Key Value Pairs

Tags: go

I'm trying to generate a map of values based on an API call that returns an interface{} of items. I'm really not sure how to explain it better, but here is my situation.

I'm using Vault to store secrets that will generate a dynamic map to be used in a cluster orchestrator. An Example being:

`secret/cluster`

secret/cluster can have infinitely nested secrets e.g.

```
secret/cluster/team1/secreta/

secret/cluster/team2/secretb/app1/
secret/cluster/global
```

secret/cluster/team1/secreta will have Key-Value Pairs that signify a secret

e.g.

```
secret/cluster/team1/secreta
username: user
password: pass
database: db1
```

```
secret/cluster/team1
checksum: xxxxx
```

I wrote a function, that will iterate through every nested cluster and return a slice of every path that needs to be checked:

```
func getChildSecrets(path string) []string {

    for _, v := range vault.List(path) {
        if strings.HasSuffix(v, "/") {
            return append([]string{path}, getChildSecrets(fmt.Sprintf("%s%s", path, v))...)
        }
    }
    return []string{path}
}
```

My next step is to set a `map[string]interface{}` based on the name secret path and its values:

```
map[cluster][team1][secreta]{username: user, password: pass, database:db1}
map[cluster][team1]{checksum:xxxx}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: It's perfectly valid to have `secreta` be both a path and a folder, so this data structure will lose data unless you maintain the trailing `/`. `vault kv put secreta a=b` `vault kv put secreta/b a=b`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to convert Vault's path's into a `map[string]interface{}`? That's not going to be very helpful because you're going to have to perform a type assertion on each read. Be warned this is a *very* expensive N^2 operation against Vault and the algorithm you've proposed could lose data because it's valid to share the same name for a folder and a leaf. Nonetheless, here you go. I think you'll find it's a lot more complicated than you expect:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    vault "github.com/hashicorp/vault/api"
)

func main() {
    // Create a client object.
    client, err := vault.NewClient(vault.DefaultConfig())
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Convert everything at the path to a map. This will only work with KV v1.
    m, err := SecretsToMap(client, "secret/")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Dump the result as JSON for easier viewing.
    j, err := json.MarshalIndent(m, "", "  ")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s", j)
}

// SecretsToMap recursively reads all paths in the root and converts them to a
// map by each path segment.
func SecretsToMap(client *vault.Client, root string) (map[string]interface{}, error) {
    var m = make(map[string]interface{})
    if err := secretsToMap(client, m, root); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return m, nil
}

func secretsToMap(client *vault.Client, m map[string]interface{}, root string) error {
    // List everything at this path
    r, err := client.Logical().List(root)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to list %s: %s", root, err)
    }

    // Do nothing if the leaf is empty - this might be undesireable depending on
    // your use case (you may want the empty leaf here with {}). Modify as
    // appropriate.
    if r == nil || len(r.Data) == 0 {
        return nil
    }

    // Type conversions to get the response as []string.
    keysRaw, ok := r.Data["keys"]
    if !ok {
        return nil
    }
    keys, ok := keysRaw.([]interface{})
    if !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("%q is not []interface{}", keysRaw)
    }
    list := make([]string, len(keys))
    for i, v := range keys {
        str, ok := v.(string)
        if !ok {
            return fmt.Errorf("%q is not string", v)
        }
        list[i] = str
    }

    // Iterate over each response
    for _, v := range list {
        // pth is the full path (root + child)
        pth := root + v

        // If this is a folder, recurse.
        if strings.HasSuffix(v, "/") {
            if err := secretsToMap(client, m, pth); err != nil {
                return err
            }
        } else {
            // Not a folde,r read the secret, handing errors and nil/empty data
            secret, err := client.Logical().Read(pth)
            if err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("failed to read secret %s: %s", pth, err)
            }

            // This might not be what you want - modify as appropriate.
            if secret == nil || secret.Data == nil {
                return nil
            }

            // Iterate over the folder parts and make a map entry if it does not
            // exist. This will panic and fail if you have leafs and folders with the
            // same name, but I'm just following your example.
            ptr := m
            for _, v := range strings.Split(root, "/") {
                p := strings.Trim(v, "/")
                if p == "" {
                    continue
                }

                // If there's no value at ptr (which is a moving target within the map),
                // create a container for data.
                if _, ok := ptr[p]; !ok {
                    ptr[p] = map[string]interface{}{}
                }

                // Advance the map pointer deeper into the map.
                ptr = ptr[p].(map[string]interface{})
            }

            // We've reached the leaf, set the data.
            ptr[v] = secret.Data
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```